# random characters trimming/missing while taking a print from chrome

Tags: google-chrome, printing, printing-web-page

I have a cloud based software for my departmental store. It used to print the bills from a html page, fine from chrome using an EPSON thermal printer.

**Chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 m**

From last 12 hours, it has started creating issues, where in some characters from within the bills anywhere in between are not coming in print. They are there in preview but not getting printed.

Same bill is printing fine from firefox. So there is some changes that has happened to chrome. I have tried uninstalling and installing fresh version of chrome. That does not help either.

Has someone faced similar issue and know how to correct it. It is really frustrating.

Following are correct version of bill and incorrect version which chrome is printing :

**Correct :**

[image]

**Incorrect :**

[image]

Comment: My clients are having the same issue. Seems to be a new issue in Chrome. Haven't found any solution for it yet.

Comment: Yes I think its a version issue, which chrome might fix soon.

Comment: Looks like we aren't alone [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=658606). But, one commenter here said the issue still existed in v55 Canary and v56 Dev.